# (kubernetes) NodePort is too slow, when the pod is running on a different node

Tags: performance, kubernetes

I have 2 nodes (node1, node2) for Kubernetes cluster.

And I created a service with NodePort that have a Pod is running on node1

When I request to the pod through node1's NodePort, it is ok. (the request has 1Mb content in the body)

But the request through node2's NodePort is too slow. (almost 5times slower than node1)

Any help here is appreciated

Edit1# 
FYI
[Calico Enviroments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtzhP.png)

Comment: Which CNI(flannel,calico,weave) are you using in your cluster. Can you check the internet speed in between two node?

Comment: The CNI is calico, and two node is running on google cloud same region. so I think the network is fast enough. following is a result of iperf [  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  10.2 GBytes  8.76 Gbits/sec @TayburRahaman

Comment: Can you check the value of this  - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_IPIP. you can change value "always" to "off" and check the result.

Comment: the CALICO_IPV4POOL_IPIP value is already off on both of calico node1 and node2 @TayburRahaman

Comment: Please provide minimal steps to repoduce the issue like k8s version, cni version?